# Object Detection with Dlib Library

Tags: machine-learning, ocr, svm, object-detection, dlib

I am trying to object detection with using dlib machine learning library.

As I've followed instructions written everything seems to be ok however I can't detect my object even on the original image. also even if I test it out on a only black image it finds a single detection. which shouldn't happen. and if I stick one of trained images to black image it finds a lot of detections which shouldn't happen either.

I did not touch train_object_detector.cpp file. it is original.

here is my sample images

[image][image] [image][image][image][image]

XML file I've created by using imglab.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='image_metadata_stylesheet.xsl'?>
<dataset>
<name>imglab dataset</name>
<comment>Created by imglab tool.</comment>
<images>
  <image file='totaldata/1.jpg'>
    <box top='0' left='1' width='61' height='64'/>
  </image>
  <image file='totaldata/2.jpg'>
    <box top='0' left='1' width='63' height='65'>
      <label>1</label>
    </box>
  </image>
  <image file='totaldata/3.jpg'>
    <box top='1' left='0' width='61' height='61'>
      <label>1</label>
    </box>
  </image>
  <image file='totaldata/4.jpg'>
    <box top='0' left='0' width='59' height='63'>
      <label>1</label>
    </box>
  </image>
  <image file='totaldata/5.jpg'>
    <box top='2' left='1' width='59' height='60'>
      <label>1</label>
    </box>
  </image>
  <image file='totaldata/6.jpg'>
    <box top='0' left='2' width='60' height='62'>
      <label>1</label>
    </box>
  </image>
</images>
</dataset>
```

screenshot of detection with only black
[image]

screenshot of detection with only black and one of trained images.

[image]

just in case this is link for the cpp file.

http://dlib.net/train_object_detector.cpp.html

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't crop your training images.  You need to give training images that look like the images you will use during test time.

In this case, part of the feature vector for the image window is extracted from areas outside the image (since your objects are cropped so tightly) and since the outside of the image is assumed to be black it's learning that your objects are always surrounded by black pixels.